# Help interpreting Oracle RMAN results

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g, rman

I am extremely new to Oracle and had to take a backup on an 11g database that is in NOARCHIVELOG mode. Below is the output. It claims that the backup failed but I have a file of appropriate size where I expected the backup to be created.

Can someone help me interpret this log?

```
Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Wed Mar 30 20:30:27 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

 connected to target database: HS (DBID=3540555849)


RMAN> RUN {

2> 

3> CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'HIGH';

4> 

5> show all;

6> 

7> shutdown immediate;

8> 

9> startup mount;

10> 

11> backup database;

12> 

13> alter database open;

14> 

15> }

16> 

17> LIST BACKUP SUMMARY ;

18> 

19> EXIT 

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog

new RMAN configuration parameters:

CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'HIGH' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE;

new RMAN configuration parameters are successfully stored


RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name HS are:

CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'HIGH' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE;
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO 'D:\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SNCFHS.ORA'; # default
database closed
database dismounted
Oracle instance shut down
connected to target database (not started)
Oracle instance started
database mounted
Total System Global Area    4275781632 bytes
Fixed Size                     2262048 bytes
Variable Size               2818575328 bytes
Database Buffers            1442840576 bytes
Redo Buffers                  12103680 bytes
Starting backup at 30-MAR-16
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=395 device type=DISK
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
input datafile file number=00005 name=D:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\HS\HS_F0_SVMC.CID
input datafile file number=00003 name=D:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\HS\UNDOTBS01.DBF
input datafile file number=00006 name=D:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\HS\AUDIT_DATA.DBF
input datafile file number=00002 name=D:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\HS\SYSAUX01.DBF
input datafile file number=00001 name=D:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\HS\SYSTEM01.DBF
input datafile file number=00007 name=D:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\HS\AUDIT_IDX.DBF
input datafile file number=00004 name=D:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\HS\USERS01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 30-MAR-16
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 03/30/2016 20:32:43
ORA-19809: limit exceeded for recovery files
ORA-19804: cannot reclaim 67108864 bytes disk space from 4322230272 limit
continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
including current control file in backup set
including current SPFILE in backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 30-MAR-16
channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 30-MAR-16
piece handle=D:\APP\ORACLE\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\HS\BACKUPSET\2016_03_30\O1_MF_NCSNF_TAG20160330T203107_CHRW1F69_.BKP tag=TAG20160330T203107 comment=NONE
channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:00:01

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================

RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================



RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 03/30/2016 20:32:43

ORA-19809: limit exceeded for recovery files

ORA-19804: cannot reclaim 67108864 bytes disk space from 4322230272 limit



Recovery Manager complete.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see what the Oracle supplied `oerr` utility says about you errors.

`[oracle@testsrv Desktop]$ oerr ora 19804`

> #### ORA-19804 cannot reclaim %s bytes disk space from %s limit
>
> **Cause:** Oracle cannot reclaim disk space of specified bytes from the
>            DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE limit.
>   **Action:** There are five possible solutions:
>             1) Take frequent backup of recovery area using RMAN.
>             2) Consider changing RMAN retention policy.
>             3) Consider changing RMAN archived log deletion policy.
>             4) Add disk space and increase DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE.
>             5) Delete files from recovery area using RMAN.
>
> #### ORA-19809 limit exceeded for recovery files
>
> **Cause:** The limit for recovery files specified by the
>           DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE was exceeded.
>   **Action:** There are five possible solutions:
>             1) Take frequent backup of recovery area using RMAN.
>             2) Consider changing RMAN retention policy.
>             3) Consider changing RMAN archived log deletion policy.
>             4) Add disk space and increase DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE.
>             5) Delete files from recovery area using RMAN.

Increase the `db_recovery_file_dest_size` size or specify format for the RMAN channel to different location.

Example

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
SQL> alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size=30G;
```

You should take care about actually disk space size of the disk which has defined as fast recovery area. If you want to store your back other location than flash recovery area then you can allocate channel as shown below.

```
RUN
{
  ALLOCATE CHANNEL disk1 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'E:\%U'; 
  BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I was low on disk space. Rooky move on my part.

Comment: And be aware that setting DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE does not reserve any disk space at the OS level, or guarantee that the specified space actually exists.  It only sets a limit on how much space oracle is to allow itself.  Plus, oracle only counts it as fra usage when it is using FRA faclities.  If you specify DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'something' and 'something' happens to be under the FRA area, this is still not counted as FRA usage, even though it is consuming disk in the FRA area.